# @function with Sass

Tags: function, sass

Scss allows defining function in itself:

```
@function grid-width($n) {
  @return $n * $grid-width + ($n - 1) * $gutter-width;
}
```

Can I write the same in Sass (the indented syntax)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, well, I fed it to sass-convert and got

```
@function grid-width($n)
  @return $n * $grid-width + ($n - 1) * $gutter-width
```